# Magento Patches (wrong names, not corresponding with version)

Tags: magento-1.7

Recently I figured that many patches I have installed in year 2014-2015 like SUPEE  1533 SUPEE-5994 have messed up names. When looking thought installed patch.list 
For 1.7.0.2, the Supee 5994 shows as
PATCH_SUPEE-5998_EE_1.14.1.0

EE stands for enterprise 1.14...  I am pretty sure when I downloaded Patch it in May 2015 as it was released, it was for 1.7.0.2 Magento community version.. I went back today to compare with currently available SUPEE 5994 from the list and looks like they were all renaimed.

What is the deal with magento naming patches with titles not corresponding with their version?

I am now thinking, if I ever need to revert the original patch, I can't event download it anymore from magento. They are now renamed. 
How to revert patches if I don't have original patch?

Answer (score 0):

To revert the Magento patch go to magento directory and use:
`sh patch_file -R`
It will revert the patch. Then download valid patch and apply it.

Comment: What if previously installed patch .sh file is deleted from directory after it was installed. How to revert?